# Preselect Filename when printing to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, automation, acrobat

Can anyone recommend a tool that will allow me to set a registry key or a INI file, or something that will preselect the filename of a PDF when I print it?

I have written code to render some HTML in a web browser control, I simply want to export that HTML file to a PDF as easily as possible.  Its been awhile since I have done this but I thought some of the free PDF printers had a registry key or an INI file I can insert a file name and that would make the SAVE dialog not appear and simply print the next file to that file name.

Comment: It might be possible to do this, but you have to specify which particular PDF printer you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[Win2PDF](http://www.win2pdf.com) has a registry API to [print to PDF while bypassing the save dialog](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/specifyinganoutputfilename.htm).  It also has an [auto-name feature](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/index.html?automatically-name-pdf.htm) that will automatically name the PDF based on the document title, the current date, and the current time.